# Is it right that every $\sigma \in \operatorname{Hom}_{F}(E,L)$ can be extended to a $\sigma' \in \operatorname{Hom}_{F}(L,L)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $L/F$ is a normal extension, and $E/F$ is subextension, i.e. $F\subset E\subset L$. 
Is it true that every $\sigma \in \newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_{F}(E,L)$ can be extended to a $\sigma' \in \Hom_{F}(L，L)$?

Comment: sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Embed $L$ in an algebraically closed field $K$ containing it as a subfield.

Since $L/E$ is algebraic and $K$ is algebraically closed, your embedding $\sigma\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,K)$ extends to an embedding $\sigma'\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(L,K)$(*).

Since $L/F$ is normal, the image of $L$ through $\sigma'$ is contained in $L$, hence $\sigma'$ belongs, in fact, to $\operatorname{Hom}_F(L,L)$.

---

(*) This is proved by considering the set $\mathscr S$ of embeddings $\tau:D\to K$ with $E\subseteq D\subseteq L$ extening $\sigma$.
Order $\mathscr S$ by $\tau_1\leq\tau_2$ if and only if $\tau_2|D_1=\tau_1$ for $\tau_i:D_i\to K$ with $D_1\subseteq D_2$.
All chains in $\mathscr S$ have upper bound, hence Zorn's lemma applies giving rise to a maximal embedding $\tau:D\to K$ with $E\subseteq D\subseteq L$ extening $\sigma$.
Then $D=L$.
Assume on contrary that there exists $\alpha\in L\setminus D$.
Let $p\in D[X]$ its irreducible polynomial and let $p^\tau\in K[X]$ denote its image under $\tau$. Let  $\varphi:D[X]\to K$ extending $\tau$ and sending $X\mapsto\beta$ where $\beta$ is a root of $p^\tau$ in $K$ (recall $K$ algebraically closed).
Then $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)=\langle p\rangle$, thus $D[\alpha]\cong D[X]/\langle p\rangle$, hence $\varphi$ induces an embedding $D[\alpha]\to K$ extending $\tau$.
This contradicts the maximality of $\tau$ and proves $D=L$.
Then $\tau:L\to K$ is the required extension of $\sigma$.

Comment: why if  $K$ is algebraically closed, embedding $\sigma\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,K)$ can be extended to  an embedding $\sigma'\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(L,K)$

Comment: I add the proof of this in my answer: it's an application of Zorn's Lemma. You can find this proof in Lang's Algebra.